# How to change column name and value depending on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change column name and value depending on condition.
My table is..

```
Roll    Name    Mark
3   Chaity  87
1   Anis    75
4   Unknown 30
2   Badol   0
```

And I want to get like this

```
Roll    Name    Grade
3   Chaity  A+
1   Anis    A
4   Unknown F
2   Badol   F
```

Where Mark and Grade mapping is as follows:

```
0 to 60 is F
61 to 79 is A
80 and above is A+
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `CASE` expression will do it:

```
SELECT
    Roll,
    Name,
    Grade = CASE 
                WHEN Mark <= 60 THEN 'F'
                WHEN Mark <= 79 THEN 'A'
                ELSE 'A+'
            END
FROM tbl
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/470346)</kbd>

Comment: I think the second case would be `WHEN Mark <80`, because 79 is still considered as A

Answer (score 2):

you can use CASE WHEN ... or create a Grade table

```
SELECT Roll, Name, Grade = case when Mark >= 80 then 'A+'
                                when Mark between 61 and 79 then 'A'
                                else 'F'
                                end
FROM   yourtable
```

using a Grade table

```
SELECT t.Roll, t.Name, g.Grade
FROM   yourtable t
       outer apply
       (
            select x.Grade
            from   GradeTable x
            where  t.Mark between x.Mark_from and x.Mark_to
       ) g
```

But isn't the grading system a bit drastic ? You either get an A or failed :(

Comment: But you still get an A at 61, which I think is nice.